# Nested types in mvc4 web api with JSON coming in null from AS3/FLEX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

Solved! Check bottom of post for solution.

So I have a web api I am working on and the gets work great and the posts work great for simple types that are only comprised of basic types. An example of one that works:

```
    public class Investigator
    {
        public int InvestigatorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

However with nested types, the nested objects come back as their default representation(0's and nulls depending on the type). Here's an example of one that is not working:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }


    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public virtual Investigator ProjectInvestigator { get; set; }

}
```

When I call the uri for posting a project all of the fields come through just fine except for the nested types, which come back in their default representations (investigator comes back with 0 for id and null for name). If I do not include an investigator in the post request the investigator object itself comes through as null instead of a default object. So I know it is at least seen by the code, however it is not deserializing correctly or something. What could be causing this and where might I be able to look to see the data that is coming in before being deserialized?

The other code sections that might be relevant are the controller:

```
 public class ProjectsController : ApiController
{
    private NovascotiaContext db = new NovascotiaContext();

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    // GET api/Projects
    public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
    {
        return db.Projects.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/Projects/5
    public Project GetProject(int id)
    {
        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return project;
    }

    // PUT api/Projects/5
    public HttpResponseMessage PutProject(int id, Project project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (id != project.ProjectId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    // POST api/Projects
    public HttpResponseMessage PostProject([FromBody]Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, project);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = project.ProjectId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }


    // DELETE api/Projects/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteProject(int id)
    {
        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Projects.Remove(project);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, project);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And the web api config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();

        // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
        // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

Edit:
The post request is being completed in as3/flex via HTTPService class:

```
var p:Project = new Project();
p.City = "ACity";
p.ProjectName = "AProjectName";
var state:data.State = new data.State();
state.StateId = 98;
state.StateName = "Tennessee";
p.State = state;
var investigator:Investigator = new Investigator();
investigator.InvestigatorId = 1;
investigator.Name = "John Doe";
p.ProjectInvestigator = investigator;
projectPostService.send(p);
```

Where projectPostService is an HTTPService object with method="POST". The strange thing is while writing this i created a simple page to hit the service and it works out so this is obviously something on communication between as3/flex and the web api. Here is the page that works:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("ready");
                var project = {
                "ProjectId": 2,
                "ProjectName": "Aprojectname",
                "State": { "StateId": 98, "StateName": "Tennessee" },
                "ProjectInvestigator": { "InvestigatorId": 1, "Name": "John Doe" }
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/api/Projects",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                    data: project,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited the title to match the more specific problem. If anyone has any experience getting this to work between as3/flex and a web api project any help would be appreciated.

Yet another edit:
It seems that the HTTPService class goes through each property on the object to be sent and turns it into a name/value pair. This works fine for the '0 depth' fields but for nested objects the fields come out to be something like "field" : "[Object object]".

Solution:
I ended up using a URLLoader in as3 for hitting the service url. For a while I was unsuccessful in posting a nested object because the nested types kept becoming empty. The solution for me was setting the content type to text, something I had overlooked earlier. For anyone else that comes across this problem, to hit a service such as the ones above, this is an example:

```
var p:Project = new Project();
p.City = "ACity";
p.ProjectName = "AProjectName";
var state:data.State = new data.State();
state.StateId = 98;
state.StateName = "Tennessee";
p.State = state;
var investigator:Investigator = new Investigator();
investigator.InvestigatorId = 1;
investigator.Name = "John Doe";
p.ProjectInvestigator = investigator;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/api/Projects");
request.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
request.data = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(p);
request.contentType = "TEXT";
request.method = "POST";
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
    trace(loader.data); //return
});
loader.load(request);
```

Comment: Could you share your raw 'post' request?